# fyne create rows in a container from a slice of containers

Tags: go, variadic-functions, fyne

I need to have a slice called rows containing a number of fyne.Container structs.
Then I need to show them all as rows in a window.

I tried doing this:

```
rows := []*fyne.Container{}
rows = append(
    rows, 
    container.New(
        layout.NewGridLayout(4),
        widget.NewLabel("Trigger"),
        widget.NewLabel("Text"),
        widget.NewLabel("Enter"),
        widget.NewLabel("Active"),
    ),
)

w.SetContent(
    container.New(
        layout.NewGridLayout(1),
        rows...
    ),
)
```

but I get

> cannot use rows (type []*fyne.Container) as type []fyne.CanvasObject in argument to container.New

And I don't understand why if I do this:

```
w.SetContent(
    container.New(
        layout.NewGridLayout(1),
        container.New(
            layout.NewGridLayout(4),
            widget.NewLabel("Trigger"),
            widget.NewLabel("Text"),
            widget.NewLabel("Enter"),
            widget.NewLabel("Active"),
        ),
        container.New(
            layout.NewGridLayout(4),
            widget.NewLabel("Trigger"),
            widget.NewLabel("Text"),
            widget.NewLabel("Enter"),
            widget.NewLabel("Active"),
        ),
    ),
)
```

It works fine... Shouldn't it be the same passing individual structs or a []type...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method expects a slice of `fyne.CanvasObject`s, which is an interface that the struct `fyne.Container` implements.

A slice of a struct type cannot be used in place of a slice of an interface type, even if the struct type satisfies the interface.

Your slice should be of the interface type  not the struct type. You can then append objects that fulfill the interface to that slice:

```
rows := []fyne.CanvasObject{}
rows = append(
    rows, 
    container.New(
        layout.NewGridLayout(4),
        widget.NewLabel("Trigger"),
        widget.NewLabel("Text"),
        widget.NewLabel("Enter"),
        widget.NewLabel("Active"),
    ),
)
```